# Show the status of all untracked files in untracked directories

Tags: svn, terminal

If I run `svn status` in a terminal, I get the status of all untracked files and directories within **tracked directories**, but I also need the untracked files and directories within **untracked directories**.

For example, if I have a directory foo that is untracked with files in it and I run `git status` I'll get the following:

```
?     /foo
?     /file1
?     /file2
```

Which is excluding the contents within foo. If I track foo with `svn add` and then run `svn status` again I'll get:

```
A     /foo
?     /foo/file
?     /foo/directory
?     /file1
?     /file2
```

Which now gives the status of the contents within foo, but I had to manually track it. Furthermore, now I can't see the status of the contents within foo/directory unless I repeat the same process.

I'm after a solution that will simply show me the status of **ALL** files and directories in the SVN repository, not just the ones within tracked directories. I should get:

```
?     /foo
?     /foo/file
?     /foo/directory
?     /foo/directory/file
?     /file1
?     /file2
```

I've searched around to no avail and none of the args for `svn status` seem to be of any help. I've tried `svn status --depth infinity` and that didn't affect it either. I've noticed that when you try to commit in TortoiseSVN, it shows you a list of all changes including all untracked files/directories within untracked directories like I'm after -- how does TortoiseSVN get its list?

Comment: So is it `git status` or `svn status`? Git does not track empty directories.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm after a solution that will simply show me the status of ALL files
>   and directories in the SVN repository, not just the ones within
>   tracked directories.

I don't see a way to do this with SVN 1.9.7 command line tools. I assume this behavior to be expected. But what use case do you have that requires you to see child items under unversioned (i.e. untracked) directories? Note that you can post your question to [users@ SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) mailing list.